# Date format(0) conversion In Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I am trying to convert the date format stored in my table with a specified format but it is not converting it to the desired format.

I have a table having data in format 15-Jan-2016 00:21:06 CEST and 6/19/2019 3:07:01 AM and I have to convert the date into DD-MON-YY hh24:mi:ss am.

I am using the below query to format the data.

```
select to_char(to_date(substr(mod,1,20),'DD-MON-YY hh24:mi:ss'),'MM-DD-YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') datetime from test where mod like '%CEST'
union all
select to_char(to_date(mod,'MM-DD-YY hh:mi:ss am'),'MM-DD-YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') datetime from test where mod  not like '%CEST';
```

It is giving proper output **0**1-15-2016 12:21:06 AM and **0**6-19-2019 03:07:01 AM. But I don't want the 0 coming before the month. Is there any specifed date format for removing the 0?

Comment: At some point you may want to consider changing the data type for your date data to be DATE. Then the formats for display in your apps, as well as manipulating the dates, becomes a very trivial exercise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply the `fm` format mask modifier. See `res_2`:

```
SQL> select to_char(sysdate, 'mm-dd-yyyy') res_1,
  2         to_char(sysdate, 'fmm-dd-yyyy') res_2
  3  from dual;

RES_1      RES_2
---------- ----------
08-13-2019 8-13-2019

SQL>
```